# How to remove some elements of list input in django admin

Tags: django, django-forms

i have a list like this in my django admin :
[image]

Do you know if it's possible to remove some elements of that list ? for example i would like to remove all "gateway" that have the status "inactive" ( status=False ).

Here gateway model :

```
class Gateway(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    logo = models.TextField()
    status = models.Boolean()
```

I don't even know if it's possible to do some filter on a list in django admin ...

thank for your help !

Comment: Yes, can you post the model that refers to the gateway? (so the one you are editing here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. You can use the [**`limit_choices_to=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) for the `ForeignKey`. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class MyModel(models.Model):
    gateway = models.ForeignKey(
        Gateway,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to=Q(status=True)
    )
```

So here we filter the set of candidate `Gateway`s such that the `status` field should be `True`.

Comment: yes thank you a lot !

Quick update, it's limit_choices_to and not limit_choices but thank <3

Comment: @ValentinGarreau: aarrghhh... Yes. Thanks! updated.